# Debugging MEX Files - Starting MATLAB with the -Dgdb does not produce a gdb prompt

Tags: matlab, gdb, mex

I was attempting to debug a MEX file (made with the -g flag). I'm on MATLAB R2016B working under MinGW64.

I don't have access to either Visual Studio 2012 nor Eclipse, so using either of those to debug wasn't possible.

So, instead, I was following this guide: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/debugging-on-linux-platforms.html

Which explains how to do it with gdb.

However, the moment I do `matlab -Dgdb` in my terminal, it just starts up the MATLAB application, with no gdb prompt in either my terminal or in MATLAB.

Did they skip a step in those instructions, or is there something obvious I missed?

EDIT: If I go against what they suggest and start gdb first by calling `gdb matlab`, then do `r -Dgdb` and then follow the instructions from that point, I end up getting that "dbmex doesn't work on the PC. See the MATLAB External Interfaces Guide for details on how to debug MEX-files."

Comment: The `-Dgdb` option is not available under Windows.

Comment: Well, that would definitely be the problem. Is there some alternative for Windows? It's not my preference, it's just all I have a key for atm.

Comment: I don't know. I only used Visual Studio for MEX debugging. I saw there is a Remote Debugging option (probably not relevant in your case).

Comment: @Rotem Does the -D option in general not work? I tried ```matlab -nojvm -nodesktop -nosplash -D"valgrind --error-limit=no --leak-check=yes --tool=memcheck -v --log-file=valgrind.log"``` but while it worked, no log file was ever created.

Comment: I never tried it... When typing `matlab.exe -h` in the console, I can't see `-D` option.

Comment: @Rotem Yeah. I see that as well. Then again, it also doesn't show ```-nojvm``` or ```-nodesktop```, but those *must* be working otherwise I wouldn't be getting the command window.

Comment: I tried `matlab -blabla`, looks like it's just being ignored

Comment: It ignores arbitrary ones, yes. But some of them definitely work.

Comment: In any case, it looks like that usage of -D is the same one as -Dgdb. They're the same command, apparently. So it doesn't look like it'll work on Windows. :/ (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html)

Comment: I don't think `-D` is needed for MEX debugging. Look for a way to do the "Debug" -> "Attach to Process" thing, like debugging MEX with Visual Studio.

Comment: Like I was saying in the original post, visual studio isn't an option at the moment.

Comment: I know... I meant that you should find a way to do "Attach to Process" with `gdb`, but it could be that It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think there was some discussion elsewhere that used the PID of MATLAB, but it was kinda tricky. I'll look into it more at some point.